# CG miner "configure: error: No mining configured in "

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-13.04

Nvidia Gt 630 cuda 5.5 running CGminer not. Cuda examples fine. Should CGminer work or is there limitations to it?

`sudo ./autogen.sh --disable-cpumining --enable-opencl && make`

Configuration Options Summary:

```
  libcurl(GBT+getwork).: Enabled: -lcurl  
  curses.TUI...........: FOUND: -lncurses

  Avalon.ASICs.........: Disabled
  BlackArrow.ASICs.....: Disabled
  BFL.ASICs............: Disabled
  BitForce.FPGAs.......: Disabled
  BitFury.ASICs........: Disabled
  Hashfast.ASICs.......: Disabled
  Icarus.ASICs/FPGAs...: Disabled
  Klondike.ASICs.......: Disabled
  KnC.ASICs............: Disabled
  ModMiner.FPGAs.......: Disabled
configure: error: No mining configured in
```

Comment: Its important to note.  That even when this question was asked that CGMiner had already removed GPU mining from the current release.

Answer (score 0):

You did not configure any miners. There is [check](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/configure.ac#L590) for enabled miners in .configure file.

All yours show **Disabled** state.

Disabled state [is set](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/configure.ac#L500) if appropriate variable was not set to `yes`.

Variable is set to **no** by default unless you supply a key for it to .configure script ([for example](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/configure.ac#L132) `--enable-avalon` ).

So, your solution is to enable at least one miner:

```
--enable-avalon
--enable-bab
--enable-bflsc
--enable-bitforce
--enable-bitfury
--enable-cointerra
--enable-bitmine_A1
--enable-drillbit
--enable-hashfast
--enable-icarus
--enable-klondike
--enable-knc
--enable-avalon2
--enable-minion
--enable-modminer
```